# How do I change git repository to which I push

Tags: git, github

Let's say I cloned someone else's repository from git

git clone [some youtube parser]

I changed it a bit and want to save it as my project. When I type git push, it says *remote: Permission to *** denied to myusername.*

Which makes sense, as it is not my repository.

My own repository has url https://github.com/myusername/Projects

I want my project to be saved in that url in a new folder called "youtube parser". How to do that?

Comment: You will need to 1) fork the project you want to make changes to into your own github account, 2) clone that forked repo to your local, 3) make changes, 4) push to your own repo. If you want to make changes to that someone elses' repo directly, you will need to submit a pull request (https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-pull-requests)

Comment: @TYZ You can just update the remote on your local repo. There's no reason to re-clone it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried?

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myusername/Projects
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: It says git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: I typed git remote set-url origin https://github.com/tbaikabulov/Projects (this is my repository and it exists)

Comment: Yes, your remote repository is not empty. You can only push an untracked branch to an empty repository.

Comment: Also the repository contains a subrepository. Is this intentional?

Comment: So, if I create a new repository, it should work?  About your 2nd question - I wanted to save all my projects in repository Projects in separate folders. Or is it better to create a new repo for every project?

Comment: I think your best option: 1) remove the `youtube-parser/.git` folder 2) `git add .` 3) `git commit -m "Add youtube project"` 4) Delete and re-create the repository on github 5) `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/tbaikabulov/Projects` 6) `git push -u origin master`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238779/discussion-between-timur-and-pieterjan).